# How do i apply this JSON to customize my Google Map

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

im trying to apply this JSON code to my Google Map:

```
[ { stylers: [ { hue: "#ff0000" } ] } ]
```

[generated from this website](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html):

That is actually made by Google, the problem is that i dont know enought about JSON to know how i apply this code and i cant find any examples using this kind of code.

Grateful for any tips or answers! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yeah, I think it's not so obvious. It doesn't help that in #9 of the Wizard, they write "style" when it should be "styles".

In the Hello World example ( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial ), change the myOptions, adding the comma after mapTypeId, then the option "styles: " and paste the JSON.

```
  function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      styles: [ { stylers: [ { hue: "#ff0000" } ] } ]
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
  }
```

Comment: Jikes, didn't know i had to use the Google Map API to get this done, I'm finaly finished, with both color and icon but this solution isn't for the faint of heart. If any one is curious on how to do this, go here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial and follow the toturials step by step, it actually makes sense in the end :p